# How would Login with Facebook work for an app with its own user database?

Tags: android, database, facebook-login

I have a question about the Login with Facebook feature that some apps have. Here's my scenario:

I currently have an Android social networking application that has its own user database and login system and users have their own username, bio, etc, and I would like to include the option for Facebook login. Currently, when a user wishes to sign up to use the app, they have to enter a new unique username/password/email and that username is then used for further requests to the database from the app and is required. So basically I have a few questions:

1. I know I can get the FB email for a user and use it in the sign up process but what about the username/password combination - should I ask for them separately?
2. Assuming that the sign up with FB is complete, when the user logs in with facebook how would I know the username? (I am guessing that I could use the email address to verify this, right?)

So I guess my main problem is how to get a username/password combination upon signup/login from facebook. Any help/suggestions are much appreciated :) Thanks

(I know that this has probably been asked a million times before but I couldn't find a good explanation/resolution to the problem and since I have a username, instead of an email address, as the user identifier, I think this complicates things a bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to the question 1, I'd say that the Facebook password, will be the password you are talking. Just that Facebook will store it, so you must allow to the Facebook users, to not have a password on your database.

The question about the username, it's more complicated to answer, and I guess that should be you who has to answer it. But I'll use his/her Facebook name, as I saw on many applications I use Facebook login.

So, as a resum:

- The email, will be the one which is related to the Facebook account
- The username, will be the name related to the Facebook account
- The password, will be the password related to the Facebook account

So, you have a problem right now at your database, because you wanted a unique username, password and email. Right now, you could have duplicateds, since it could be possible that a user uses his email and his Facebook account(with same email). So, I'll use either 2 tables, "FacebookUsers" and "Users" either a unique table with a new field, that will distinguish the Facebook users, and the regular users.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for the reply :) I think this makes sence - I guess I could generate a unique username from their Facebook name and use that in my database. As for the email and password - they don't have to be unique but need to be present at signup. I was thinking that I could simply check if the user is using FB login at my server and if he is, I could simply not add a password in my database. This way I will be able to later disallow them to edit their password since it will be stored by facebook.

Comment: BUT doesn't that mean that if a user signs up with Facebook, then logs out and then wishes to login without FB, they would have to create a new account since the FB account would not have a password associated with it?

Comment: Simple, just give always the chance to log in with Facebook. That will be my recommendation. It's not a big deal, since you already have the Facebook login implemented, you only have to put it everywhere you think it'll be necessary to log in.

Comment: got another related question when using fb login, should we store fb user data in our db too? Don't we need to update this data so that they're up to date? How often then should we update this?

Comment: If I remember well, you could do that everytime the user logs in your app. Or you could set up a 'refresh' period (daily, weekly, monthly...).